# Требуются ли в предложении изменения?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, редактура, стилистическая-сочетаемость

**Девушка стояла в полумраке, окруженная ореолом света, на возвышенности высотой в четыре метра, напоминающая собой лестницу.**

Смысл в том, что всё вокруг окутано мраком  и лишь возвышенность, на которой стоит девушка, была освещена. Но кажется, будто в предложении что-то не так и требует редактуры.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, во-первых, "*девушка ... напоминающая собой лестницу*" выглядит забавно. Лучше все-таки согласовать падеж "*на возвышенности ... напоминающей лестницу*". "Собой" тут можно смело опустить.

Если говорить о стилистике, предложение выглядит довольно неуклюже. Точное указание высоты выглядит отрывком из какой-то строительной документации; для художественного текста лучше некоторая неопределённость. Например, замените "*высотой в четыре метра*" на "*высотой метра четыре*", и текст сразу будет выглядеть более художественно.

Вообще вторую часть предложения: "*на возвышенности высотой в четыре метра, напоминающая собой лестницу*" я бы записал, например, как "*на похожей на лестницу возвышенности, метра четыре высотой*". Как минимум, это более живой язык.

Comment: спасибо за объяснение и поправку... Да, вы правы, конечно

Answer (score 1):

При построении предложения я бы сначала выяснила последовательность (утрированно: кто, где и "в каком виде" стоял?), а потом бы уже производила согласования.

Стояла (где?) — в полумраке, на возвышенности;
на возвышенности (какой?) — высотой метра в четыре и напоминающей [собой] лестницу (выделила бы как вставку, но можно поставить и запятые);
девушка (какая?) — окруженная ореолом света.

Компонуем — может, подойдет?
**В полумраке, на возвышенности — высотой метра в четыре и напоминающей собой лестницу — стояла девушка, окруженная ореолом света.**